# how to find a symbolic variable in a symbolic expression in matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a vector of symbolic expressions like this in matlab:

```
 (p4*x15 - (p2*p3*x3*x5)/(p1*x2))/p22
 (p7*x11 + p20*x11 + p17*x16 + p19*x16 - p6*x4*x10)/p22
```

I'd like to find the expression(s) where e.g. 'x2' is present. Any idea how can I do that? 
Thanks!

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: if you want to just get expressions contains specific variable, You can try with function children(Expression) and check in the cell array(return from children command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example

```
syms p1 p2 p3 p4 p6 p7 p17 p19 p20 p22
syms x2 x3 x4 x5 x10 x11 x15 x16
s(1) = (p4*x15 - (p2*p3*x3*x5)/(p1*x2))/p22;
s(2) = (p7*x11 + p20*x11 + p17*x16 + p19*x16 - p6*x4*x10)/p22;
```

you can use [`symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html):

```
v = arrayfun(@(x)any(symvar(s)==x2),s);
```

or you can use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html):

```
v = arrayfun(@(x)~isempty(strfind(char(x),'x2')),s);
```

Comment: I think the strfind approach is prone to false positives. For example `x21` or `bx2`. Perhaps use `regexp` instead.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: That is correct (e.g., switch to searching for `'x1'` in the example above). But it should be faster if used judiciously.